# Recoil doen't work with Next.js 13 when building

Tags: next.js, react-state, recoiljs

I used Recoil as a client component, but when I want to build it, next stay in building condition and it repeates timeout, so I can't build.

It seems that Recoil doen't work with Next.js 13. Do you know any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Recoil doesn't work with SSR SERVER SIDER RENDERING. You can use it other state management like user auth handling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).